# mtu of routers bigger than endpoints

Tags: router, mtu

we have 30 remote sites, connected thru leased lines.
our provider setups the routers , we can only  read snmp info.

on the routers, most of the ifaces have mtu of 1500, but a few ones have  bigger values.

the computers on the sites use ipv4 and we dont use jumbo frames, so their mtu is 1500

question : are there any case where bigger mtu on the routers can give problems ?

Comment: The MTU is on a link. Ethernet links have an MTU of 1500. Other layer-2 protocols have other MTUs, especially WAN layer-2 protocols. Wi-Fi actually has a bigger MTU than ethernet. Problems may arise when an MTU in a path is smaller than the starting MTU, which is what fixes the size of the packet. A packet size will not increase along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this wouldn't be a problem. MTU sizing becomes a problem if the endpoints expect a certain MTU size, but the MTU size is smaller somewhere along the path, causing fragmentation or if the DF bit is set, an error and the endpoint will have to retransmit.

If the routers in between endpoints have higher MTU's than the endpoints, fragmentation will not happen and you won't have any issues.